# Binding a key to elisp find-file function

Tags: elisp

I tried the below elisp expression to bind the "F5" key to load a file in a buffer.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") '(find-file "/etc/fstab"))
```

which throws error

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, (find-file "/etc/fstab")
```

in the mini buffer.

What is the error in the elisp expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error says: It's not a command. An command is a function with a `interactive` form.
Try:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda () (interactive) (find-file "/etc/fstab")))
```